# Cross apply or unpivot?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am new to SQL and I apologize if this a weird question...

SO I have a query using CTE where I get the output from each of those as follows:

CTE 1 -

```
Plan 1, date1_plan1, date2_plan1, clientnum
```

CTE 2

```
Plan 2, date1_plan2, date2_plan2, date3_plan2, clientnum
```

CTE 3

```
Plan 3, date1_plan3, date2_plan3, clientnum
```

I did manage to get all the output together using Full join since the clientnum is the key all in one row. But what I really want is something like this in three separate rows. I would have used UNION ALL but the number of fields is not the same and I do not want to use dummy values. I have been looking at cross apply and unpivot but don;t know how I could use it in this situation.

Desired output:

```
Plan 1, date1_plan1, date2_plan1, clientnum  
Plan 2, date1_plan2, date2_plan2, date3_plan2, clientnum
Plan 3, date1_plan3, date2_plan3, clientnum
```

OR a transpose of the above. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Don't treat SQL like a spreadsheet. In a spreadsheet, it's fine for values in different cells of the same column to have different data types. Not so in SQL. The data type of each column *matters*, so trying to have `date3_plan2` in the same column as `clientnum` is problematic. Can you not do this operation, which sounds like a *presentational* issue, at a higher layer (e.g. inside an application or report builder)?

Comment: UNION is fine, just set it out differently. Put clientnum as column 2 instead, select null for date3 for the CTEs where it doesn't exist, and the problem is solved.